# Flutter project runs on android but fails to build on iOS. How to debug?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a project that runs on android but fails on IOS. I can't understand how to debug the problem.
I am using Mac m1.

Here is flutter doctor -v:

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on macOS 11.2.2 20D80 darwin-arm, locale en-IN)
> • Flutter version 1.22.6 at /Users/prashantpandey/Desktop/programming/flutterhome/flutter
> • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (7 weeks ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
> • Engine revision 2f0af37152
> • Dart version 2.10.5
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 30.0.3)
> • Android SDK at /Users/prashantpandey/Library/Android/sdk
> • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
> • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
> • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
> • CocoaPods version 1.10.1
>
> [!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
> ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
> ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
>
> [✓] Connected device (1 available)
> • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • 4B755BC3-6207-4FB8-96EE-C5C2F23453CA • ios •
> com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)

Here is the debug console:

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                            7.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[2470]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x1f81ec188) and ?? (0x11668c2b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[2470]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x1f81ec1d8) and ?? (0x11668c308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_audio_recorder-0.5.5/ios/Classes/SwiftFlutterAudioRecorderPlugin.swift:72:123: error: type 'AVAudioSession.Category' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'playAndRecord'
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(convertFromAVAudioSessionCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord), with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)
                                                                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_audio_recorder-0.5.5/ios/Classes/SwiftFlutterAudioRecorderPlugin.swift:160:58: error: function produces expected type 'AVAudioSessionRecordPermission'; did you mean to call it with '()'?
                permission = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                             ()
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_audio_recorder-0.5.5/ios/Classes/SwiftFlutterAudioRecorderPlugin.swift:215:15: error: value of type 'AVAudioSession.Category' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'rawValue'
            return input.rawValue
                   ~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/FlutterWebViewController.swift:107:34: warning: 'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes
                UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.insertSubview(self.myView!, at: 0)
                                     ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/InAppBrowserManager.swift:91:64: warning: 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the statusBarManager property of the window scene instead.
                self.previousStatusBarStyle = UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle.rawValue
                                                                   ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/InAppBrowserManager.swift:98:52: warning: 'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes
            let baseWindowLevel = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowLevel
                                                       ^
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/InAppWebViewOptions.swift:79:74: warning: 'javaScriptEnabled' was deprecated in iOS 14.0: Use WKWebPagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript to disable content JavaScript on a per-navigation basis
                realOptions["javaScriptEnabled"] = configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled
                                                                             ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/MyCookieManager.swift:120:16: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
                if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                   ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/MyCookieManager.swift:12:7: note: enclosing scope here
    class MyCookieManager: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
          ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/MyCookieManager.swift:149:24: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
                        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                           ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/MyCookieManager.swift:12:7: note: enclosing scope here
    class MyCookieManager: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
          ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:29:16: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                   ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariBrowserOptions: Options<SafariViewController> {
                 ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:58:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:62:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:58:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:62:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:162:17: warning: 'scanHexInt32' was deprecated in iOS 13.0
            scanner.scanHexInt32(&hexInt)
                    ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:29:16: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                   ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariBrowserOptions: Options<SafariViewController> {
                 ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:58:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:62:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:58:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:62:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/prashantpandey/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/ios/Classes/SafariViewController.swift:162:17: warning: 'scanHexInt32' was deprecated in iOS 13.0
            scanner.scanHexInt32(&hexInt)
                    ^
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)
```

This is pubspec.yaml

```
    dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  carousel_slider: ^1.3.0
  provider: ^4.0.4
  image_picker: 0.6.7+7
  file_picker: ^1.5.0+2
  pdf: ^1.4.1
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.1.4
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.0.0+10
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.12
  flutter_custom_clippers: ^1.0.0
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.22+1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+3
  agora_rtc_engine: ^1.0.13
  permission_handler: ^3.0.0
  url_launcher: ^5.4.2
  share: ^0.6.3+6
  package_info: ^0.4.0+16
  device_id: ^0.2.0
  flutter_widgets: ^0.1.12
  google_fonts: ^0.2.0
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^1.0.0
  flutter_screen_recording: ^1.0.9  
  open_file: ^3.0.1
  flutter_inappwebview: ^4.0.0+4
  flutter_spinkit: "^4.1.2"
  flutter_webrtc: ^0.2.8
  random_string: ^2.1.0
  dynamic_theme: ^1.0.1
  flutter_statusbar_manager: ^2.0.0
  shimmer: ^1.1.1
  avatar_glow: ^1.2.0
  audioplayers: ^0.16.1
  flutter_linkify: ^3.1.3
  firebase_storage: ^4.0.1
  flutter_open_whatsapp: ^0.1.2
  flutter_audio_recorder: ^0.5.5
  bottom_navy_bar: ^5.4.0
  easy_localization: ^2.3.3
  video_player: ^1.0.1
  youtube_explode_dart: ^1.4.4
  youtube_player_flutter: 7.0.0+7
  youtube_player_iframe: ^1.2.0+2
  wakelock: ^0.2.1+1
  image: ^2.1.19
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that your deployment target is same everywhere and for every pods you used like in my case i used 12.0 everywhere as my default development info.
Here are few screen snips for your help:

[image]

[image]

[image: Same deployment target you need to add for all the pod files added. I don't know if there is any one click way to change deployment target for all but for now i am doing it manually one by one.]

As we know that m1 mac runs on arm based processor and thus few things like cocoa pods and ffi needs to be build based on that.
After a long research i came up with few steps which will definitely help every-time you stuck with xcode flutter application build for m1 mac.

## To install completely cocoapods on Mac with M1 chip (Apple Silicon), please follow those steps:

## Cocoa Pods Installation in M1

- sudo gem install cocoapods
- sudo gem install ffi
- arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
- sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin

## Install ffi

- sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

#update repo

- arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update

## Flutter iOS builds

- flutter clean
- flutter build ios

## Re-install dependency in iOS folder of flutter project

- arch -x86_64 pod install